# Get Elasticsearch response in DataTable in C#.Net

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I m new to `Elasticsearch 2.1.1`, I want to Ask you how to fetch records from `index` using `Suggest` and convert it to `DataTable`. I've installed Nest NuGet Packages and all in my project.

I have this block of code which I want it from Elasticsearch in DataTable format

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/music/_suggest?pretty' -d '{
    "song-suggest" : {
        "text" : "n",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "suggest"
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've some blocks of `code` it should fulfill your requirements.

As you said you are new to `Elasticsearch`, so I shwoing you first how to initialize connection.

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")); 
var clientElasticSearchNet = new ElasticsearchClient(settings);
```

then use

```
var ElasticSearchNetQuery = new { music = new { "n", completion = new { field = "name_suggest" } } };

    ElasticsearchResponse<string> result = clientElasticSearchNet.Suggest<string>("music", ElasticSearchNetQuery);
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(result.Response.ToString());           
        var hitsCount = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)(json["music"].First["options"])).Count;
        DataTable dtEsReponnse = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < hitsCount; i++)
        {                
            dtEsReponnse = ConvertJSONToDataTable(json["music"].First["options"][i].ToString());
        }
```

I have created one function which will return Datatable.

```
protected DataTable ConvertJSONToDataTable(string jsonString)
    {  
        string[] jsonParts = Regex.Split(jsonString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), "},{");
        List<string> dtColumns = new List<string>();
        foreach (string jp in jsonParts)
        {
            string[] propData = Regex.Split(jp.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
            foreach (string rowData in propData)
            {
                try
                {
                    int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                    string n = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1);
                    string v = rowData.Substring(idx + 1);
                    if (!dtColumns.Contains(n))
                    {
                        dtColumns.Add(n.Replace("\"", ""));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Error Column Name : {0}", rowData));
                }

            }
            break; 
        }        
        foreach (string c in dtColumns)
        {
            if (!dt.Columns.Contains(c.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "").Trim())) {
                dt.Columns.Add(c.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "").Trim());
            }            
        }        
        foreach (string jp in jsonParts)
        {
            string[] propData = Regex.Split(jp.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
            DataRow nr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (string rowData in propData)
            {
                try
                {
                    int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                    string n = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "").Replace("\r\n", "").Trim(); //replaced
                    string v = rowData.Substring(idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
                    nr[n] = v;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    continue;
                }

            }
            dt.Rows.Add(nr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Is this code you looking for?

Comment: hey @dipesh thank you a lot for your reply and brief code explanation Let me implement it on my side, then I'll revert whether its working or not

Comment: Sure!! :) import required libraries !

Comment: Hey thanx it worked flawlessly after few chnages :) saved my day